# freeing memory inside the pointer of structure

Tags: c, free

I have this structure

```
typedef struct Rectangle{
  char *name;
  int size;
}RCG;

typedef struct Shapes{
   RCG *rectangle;
}SHP;
```

Here is the problem of mine I dynamically allocated the RCG with 20 ;

```
 SHP shp;
 shp.rectangle = (RCG*)malloc(sizeof(RCG *) * 20)
```

also allocated memory to the name of rectangle inside the pointer;

```
shp.rectangle[0].name = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
shp.rectangle[0].name = "big";
```

how can I free the name??
what i did is

```
free(shp.rectangle[0].name);
```

it gives me an error of "**the heap may be corrupted**"

I use visual studio 2010

Comment: I assume that you want to allocate memory for 20 rectangles; the code for that would be  `shp.rectangle = (RCG*)malloc(sizeof(RCG) * 20)`. Your original code reserves space for 20 _pointers_ (`type *` is a pointer to a type).

Answer (score 2):

When you use the following line

```
shp.rectangle[0].name = "big";
```

You are setting the pointer to a different location than the original return value of `malloc`.

What you probably want instead is the following.

```
memcpy(shp.rectangle[0].name, "big", strlen("big") + 1)
```

Also, whether the pointer is inside a structure is not relevant. You would have the same issue even if the pointer was not defined inside a structure.

Update: As mentioned in the comment below, since we dealing with strings in this particular case, it is probably more appropriate to use the function `strncpy` instead of the more general `memcpy`.

```
strncpy(shp.rectangle[0].name, "big", 10*sizeof(char))
```

Note that `10*sizeof(char)` is hardcoded above because that is the size of the earlier `malloc`.

Comment: Why not use str(n)cpy?

Comment: @PeterSchneider, In this case you're probably right, but I am showing `memcpy` instead because I wanted to emphasize that **memory** is being copied, and that the OP's problem is more general than strings.

Answer (score 0):

This: `shp.rectangle[0].name = "big";` does not copy the chars into the allocated space but assigns the address of the string "big" to the pointer name. The allocated memory is not referenced any longer anywhere so you lost any way of freeing it. Instead you try to free the string "big" which is part of your executable, actually.

memcpy or even better strcpy is commonly used for copying strings; those will assign to each char in name the corresponding value in "big".